# Recursive Mergesort on java

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I am practicing Algorithms question on merge sort. I build a java program on merge sort. I think there is some logical error in my code.

This is my output:

```
    Array length = 6
     value of q 2
    value of q 1
    value of q 0
9 1073741823 left end -----m(0,0,1)
6 1073741823 right end -----m(0,0,1)
remaining element left
6 9 0 0 0 0 -------------------
9 6 1073741823 left end -----m(0,1,2)
5 1073741823 right end -----m(0,1,2)
remaining element left
5 9 6 0 0 0 -------------------
value of q 4
value of q 3
0 1073741823 left end -----m(3,3,4)
8 1073741823 right end -----m(3,3,4)
remaining element right
5 9 6 0 8 0 -------------------
0 8 1073741823 left end -----m(3,4,5)
2 1073741823 right end -----m(3,4,5)
remaining element left
5 9 6 0 2 8 -------------------
9 6 5 1073741823 left end -----m(0,2,5)
0 8 2 1073741823 right end -----m(0,2,5
remaining element left
0 8 2 9 6 5 -------------------
0 8 2 9 6 5
```

This is my code:

```
public class MergeSort{
    private int[] digits;
    private  static int[] dummy;
    private  int length;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] digits = {9,6,5,0,8,2};
        System.out.println("Array length = "+digits.length);
        MergeSort ms = new MergeSort();
        ms.sort(digits);


        for(int a :dummy){
            System.out.print(a+" ");
        }
    }
    void sort(int [] digits){
        this.digits=digits;
        length=digits.length;
        dummy= new int[length];
        mergesort(0,length-1);
    }

    void mergesort(int p,int r){
        int q;
        if(p < r){
            q = (p + r) / 2;

            System.out.println("value of q "+q);
            mergesort(p,q);
            mergesort(q+1,r);
            merge(p,q,r);
            System.out.println("-------------------");
        }
    }

    void merge(int p,int q,int r){
        int i,j,k;
        int n1=q-p+1;
        int n2 =r-q;
        int [] left = new int[n1+1];
        int [] right = new int[n2+1];
        int [] arr=new int[n1+n2];
        for(i = 0; i<n1;i++){
            left[i]= digits[p+i];
            //System.out.print(left[i]+" ");
        }

        for(j = 0; j < n2; j++){
            right[j]= digits[q+j+1];
            //System.out.print(left[j]+" ");
        }
        left[n1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
        right[n2] = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;

        for(i = 0; i < left.length; i++){
            System.out.print(left[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("left end -----m("+p+","+q+","+r+")");
        for(j = 0; j < right.length; j++){
            System.out.print(right[j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("right end -----m("+p+","+q+","+r+")");

        i=0;
        j=0;
        for(k = p; k < r; k++){  
        if(left[i]<right[j]){
            dummy[k]=left[i];
            i++;
        }

        else {
             dummy[k] = right[j];
             j++;
        } 
    }

    while(i<n1)
        dummy[k]=left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
        System.out.println("remaining element left");
    }

    while(j<n2){
        dummy[k]=right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
        System.out.println("remaining element right");
    }

        for(int a: dummy){
            System.out.print(a+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your question and your code (proper indentation, please).

Comment: now see the code its formatted properly:)

Answer (score 0):

For merge sort to work it needs to take results of previews smaller calculation and use them for next stage of calculation but your results are stored in dummy that is never used as source for the next calculation only as storage. I would sugest to make merge and mergeSort functions return values it is much more readable and cleaner here is my version if you want

```
public class MergeSort {

public static void main(String ...args){
    int[]array = {9,6,5,0,8,2};
    String sortedResultToPrint = Arrays.toString(sort(array));
    System.out.println(sortedResultToPrint);
}
public static int[] sort(int[] array) {
    int[] result = mergSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
    return result;
}

private static int[] mergSort(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    int[] result = null;
    if (start < end) {
        int midle = (start + end) / 2;
        int[] left = mergSort(array, start, midle);
        int[] right = mergSort(array, midle + 1, end);
        result = merge(left, right);
    } else {
        result = new int[]{array[start]};
    }
    return result;
}

private static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
    int[] result = new int[left.length + right.length];

    int leftPtr = 0;
    int rightPtr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        // Copyed all the left part only right remains
        if (leftPtr >= left.length) {
            result[i] = right[rightPtr++];
        }

        // Copyed all the right part only left remains
        else if (rightPtr >= right.length) {
            result[i] = left[leftPtr++];
        }

        //Right is smaller than left
        else if (right[rightPtr] < left[leftPtr]) {
            result[i] = right[rightPtr++];
        }

        // Left is smaller than right
        else {
            result[i] = left[leftPtr++];
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

}